# How can you get custom iOS document type icons to show up?

Tags: xcode, icons, document, uti

I've created a custom document type (.TBVM) and can import and export such files from my app.  However, I cannot get the icon associated with that file type to show up anywhere (e.g., in iCloud, as an attachment to a text message, etc).

Here are the parameters I have set up in .plist.  Any help in figuring out where I've gone wrong would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check if this is the same situation as yours: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26510374/2124535

Comment: Hi Nathan - I don't know that it was the same situation, but it pointed me in the right direction -- I needed to add CFBundleTypeExtensions property under the Item0 Document types -- now when I export to Messages for example, the icon shows up.  Thanks for the nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Great. You should submit your own answer explaining what you did so it can help other users

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add CFBundleTypeExtensions property under the Item0 Document types.  With that addition, icons started showing up on my iPad when files were attached to Messages or emails.